# Setting the selected value of an inline attribute initialisation of a Kendo DropDownList

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I can't get the following code to set the drop down list up correctly with the selected value, everything else works; it gets populated correctly, uses the correct fields, but will not select the selected value.

Here is my razor view code:

```
<select id="location" name="location" data-role="dropdownlist" 
    data-text-field="name" data-value-field="value" 
    data-source="allocationGalleryDataSouce" 
    title="Please search for and select a location." 
    style="width:250px;" 
    data-value="@(location==null?"":location.LocationIdentifier)" >
</select>
```

I can see in the HTML rendered that the value is being set with the correct value but is just not being used by Kendo DropDownList.

Comment: Can you put a runnable example in JSBin / JSFiddle so we can debug it?

Comment: Sorry I've worked around the problem by creating the drop down instance in javscript.  I've got a deadline for a demo tomorrow but maybe after then I can recreate it in a fiddle for you.

Comment: you can check my solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31019818/4318229