# Kendo MVVM Dropdown - How to set initial value based on other data?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-mvvm

I have the following html for a Kendo MVVM DropDownList:

```
                <select id="responseTypeDDL"
                    data-role="dropdownlist"
                    data-text-field="SystemResponseTypeCode"
                    data-value-field="SystemResponseTypeId"
                    data-bind="value: selectedSystemResponseTypeCode, source: responseTypes">
                </select>
```

This is my view model:

```
        SC.ViewModels.Reference.ResponseTypeDataSource.read();

        var responseTypeDDL = kendo.observable({
            responseTypes: SC.ViewModels.Reference.ResponseTypeDataSource,
            selectedSystemResponseTypeCode: null,
            setSelectedSystemResponseTypeCode: function (code) {
                this.selectedSystemResponseTypeCode = code;
            },
        });

        kendo.bind($("#responseTypeDDL"), responseTypeDDL);

        // after reading data, I call the method to set the selected value like this:
        self.ResponseTypeDDL.setSelectedSystemResponseTypeCode(results.code);
```

The ResponseTypeDataSource.read() method returns a list of "XML", "JSON". This is the SystemResponseTypeCode field. I also read another data item from the database
and check its response type. Let's say it is "JSON". How do I set the drop down to have "JSON" selected?

Comment: Can you please update the question with code where you have tried setting the value of the Dropdown?

Comment: I haven't tried to set the value. I don't know where to begin...

Comment: You can set the same way you have set your Dropdown, if you want to bind the view after the details are loaded. For example see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/D_Learning/m9W3g/

Comment: I added value to data-bind and also the setSelectedSystemResponseTypeCode function, but a new value is never set as the selected one.

Comment: Try using the example flow and code shown in **http://jsbin.com/eqimiz/176/edit** which is provided and explained by Telerik Admin at **http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-with-mvvm-binding-to-the-data-value-field-and-not-the-object**

Comment: But all that does is show what was selected. I want to go the other way, as it were. I want to have a drop down with some items in it. It will default to having the first item from the data source selected. This happens now. Now, I want to read a value from a database, and cause THAT value to now be selected in the drop down. Seems like it should be pretty simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all this part seems to be wrong**

```js
setSelectedSystemResponseTypeCode: function (code) {
    this.selectedSystemResponseTypeCode = code;
},
```

You should make sure to call `set()` method while modifying an observed variable, otherwise it might not update the bindings:

```js
this.set("selectedSystemResponseTypeCode", code);
```

---

**And for your actual question**

You need to set `data-value-primitive="true"` in order to work with just the id ([Kendo Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-valuePrimitive)) (Please note changes below, `value: selectedSystemResponseTypeId`)

```html
<select id="responseTypeDDL"
    data-role="dropdownlist"
    data-text-field="SystemResponseTypeCode"
    data-value-field="SystemResponseTypeId"
    data-value-primitive="true"
    data-bind="value: selectedSystemResponseTypeId, source: responseTypes">
</select>
```

```js
SC.ViewModels.Reference.ResponseTypeDataSource.read();

var responseTypeDDL = kendo.observable({
    responseTypes: SC.ViewModels.Reference.ResponseTypeDataSource,
    selectedSystemResponseTypeCode: null,
    selectedSystemResponseTypeId: null,
    setSelectedSystemResponseTypeId: function (id) {
        this.set("selectedSystemResponseTypeId", id);
    },
});

kendo.bind($("#responseTypeDDL"), responseTypeDDL);

// Get your id
var id = ...    
responseTypeDDL.setSelectedSystemResponseTypeId(id);
```

Working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/AbIm/8

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to manually set the value in dropdownlist without resorting to 
data-value-primitive="true"
because i need to access the selected value and display other fields.

Here's the solution:

```
var id = 1004;
var dataItem = responseTypeDDL.responseTypes.get(id); //get the id in your datasource
responseTypeDDL.set("selectedsystemResponse", dataItem);
```